# Returning clause in insert statement in Mulesoft connector

Tags: postgresql, mule-component, sql-returning

We are using Mulesoft for sending bunch of records from one system to another. The target is on Postgres DB. I know there is query like

```
INSERT INTO T1 (C2,C3) VALUES (V2, V3) returning to_char(C1,'99') into var_id;
```

in postgres which returns the generated id for the newly created record. Is there any way to do the same thing in Mulesoft connector so that we get to know which column data is generated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this could work, but maybe you could use an `INSERT` query into a `Select` Operation in the Database connector.

Comment: What would be the syntax? Could you please give an example?